# Why @Mock and doReturn().when() behave differently for 2 different objects

Tags: mockito, junit5

I have two @Component classes: ClassA, ClassB. In Test class, When I use @Mock on ClassA and ClassB and tries to call their method using doReturn(),when().methodCall(), it returns correct object for ClassA, but returns null for ClassB.

**Note**: ClassA and ClassB are @Component classes.    And all methods are public.
Here is the code snippet:

```
@Repository
public class ClassC{

    @Autowired
    ClassA classA;
    @Autowired
    ClassB classB;

    public void method(){
        List<Account> listAccounts = classA.getAccounts("");
        Event event = classB.getEvent("","");

        if(event != null){  // It always comes null.

        }

    }

}

public class TestClassC {

    @Mock
    ClassA classA;
    @Mock
    ClassB classB;

    @InjectMocks
    ClassC classC;

    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
        List<Account> listAcc = new ArrayList<>();
        Event event =  new Event();
        doReturn(listAcc).when(classA).getAccounts("");

        doReturn(event).when(classB).getEvent("", "");

        classC.method();
    }
}
```

**Result**: listAcc is correct. But event always comes null.

Comment: The test doesn’t show what is happening, so I assume you’re using a debugger to check. Can you add an assertion to the test to verify the expected behaviour? That simplifies reproducing the issue for others. Moreover, which Mockito version do you use?

Comment: @johanneslink : Hi, yes, I am debugging it. I am using junit-jupiter-version: 5.8.2. The only issue with getting event = null is, I am not able to cover all code under code coverage. Assertion will work well, whether event = null or not.   The thing is that why this strange behavior is ?

Comment: Please show us the signatures of getAccounts and getEvents. Also, are you using mockito-core or mockito-inline? What version?

Comment: @Lesiak: It is mockito-core:4.0.0  Methods are public.  public List<Account> getAccounts(String acc){}       public Event getEvent(String eventId, String eventName){}

Comment: I suspected a final method, but this is not the case. My second guess is some double-initialization of mocks. Debug if mocks used in `doReturn` calls are the same as mocks that get passed to classC. How do you initialize your mocks and class under test?

Comment: Class under Test is ClassC and I have used @InjectMocks for it. The thing is that Mocks classA and classB are fine. They are not null. Means, they got mocked well. I am able to call their methods. But the return value for classB.getEvent() is coming null.

Comment: But do you use MockitoExtension, openMocks/initMocks call or both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254058/discussion-between-anish-mittal-and-lesiak).

Comment: Without annotations on the class or without initializing the mocks manually, no mock objects are created. This would mean that your ClassC doesn't have any fields set (unless you run a `@SpringBootTest` or similar; but then it doesn't use mocks, but real components from your application context)